# Systems crashes sometimes with VLC media player

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, vlc

It has been 'bugging' me for a while now, sometimes when i open or put VLC media player on fullscreen on my MacBook Air, my screen freezes,audio keeps playing, cursor stops moving and I am not able to do anything, cannot even open Task manager(Force quit applications), and I am forced to shut down my system using the power key. Not necessarily with High definition videos. Opening and closing multiple videos seem to fuel the process. No issues with any other app. I am using VLC 2.2.8 on High Sierra 10.13.2.

Comment: Does it do it with any other video player?  What about in Safe Mode (hold Shift while you boot)?  Also, what MacBook model are you using?

Comment: Most recent VLC version is 3.0.1, maybe it's time to upgrade?